# Type in assembly is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, object, serialization, clone

I have an `entityClass` that I wish to serialize as a clone. But this class has a reference assembly from a custom framework which I don't have the access to the code. Whenever I try to serialize `entityClass` object, it throw the exception,

> Type ... in Assembly '..., Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that the problem is that a field/property on your object is of the problem type, you need to either mark the field/property as [NonSerialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) or create a derivative of the type which is marked as [Serializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you derive from the type and mark it as Serialized, you will most likely have to create the serialization logic yourself. This requires you to implement [ISerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) and a serialization constructor which takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext.

[This link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/how-to-serialize-an-object-using-an-iserializable-interface/) may help.

Answer (score 8):

If you have PropertyChanged event then set it to [NonSerialized] in all objects(classes) you will Serialize.

```
    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: This fixed a similar problem for me.  All events in C# must be [field: NonSerialized] or they try to 'save' them as a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, try adding Serializable attribute to your class.
Example:

```
   [Serializable]
   public class MyModel 
   {
      public int? ID { get; set; }
      ...
   }
```