# Google Calendar API - Bot Framework: "CalendarService is not marked as serializable"

Tags: c#, serialization, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm pretty new in C# programming and trying to manage the google calendar via a chatbot.

I built a ChatBot in C # with Visual Studio based on the Template for Microsoft Bot Framework, and it **works**.

I followed this https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet guide to manage the calendar through a Visual C # Console Application project, and it **works**.

The problem is that when I try to bring the calendar link back to the Bot project (following the same procedure that I used for the Application project) I get the following problem:

> Exception: The type 'Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService' in the
>   assembly 'Google.Apis.Calendar.v3, Version = 1.30.0.1032, Culture =
>   neutral, PublicKeyToken = 4b01fa6e34db77ab' is not marked as
>   serializable.

It seems to me a problem with the library, but I can not figure out how to get out of it. Some idea? Thanks so much

Comment: Have you checked [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307365/type-in-assembly-is-not-marked-as-serializable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it alone. The problem was that I created the CalendarServices one time and so when I got to call them, they created serialization issues. Now instead, every time I need to use them I make a new creation, so the problem does not arise.