# serialization exemption when saving a binary file in Unity3d

Tags: c#, list, serialization, binaryfiles

I'm trying to save two elements, a string and a list of strings to a binary file. I have the class set outside the main script:

```
}
 the main script
}
[Serializable]
class SaveManager
{
    public string Info;
    public List<InfoSheetList> InfoSheetList ;

}
```

Then the function that calls it all

```
public void GetInfoSheet() 
    {

        DatabaseManager.Instance.SQLiteInit();
        string Info = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Info");
        string date = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Date");
        string Date=date.Replace("/","-");
        string Name = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Name");
        string FilePath="C:/InfoSheets";

        DatabaseManager.Instance.SQLiteInit();
        InfoSheetList.Clear();
        InfoSheetList= DatabaseManager.Instance.MakeInfoSheetList();
        Debug.Log("How many in the list " + InfoSheetList.Count);

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream fs = File.Create(FilePath + "/" +Date+Name+"InfoSheet.gig");
        Debug.Log (fs);
        SaveManager sm= new SaveManager();
        sm.Info=Info;
        sm.InfoSheetList=InfoSheetList;
        //PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll ();

        bf.Serialize(fs, sm);
        fs.Close();
        Debug.Log(sm+ "Saved!");
```

Only I'm getting an exception-
SerializationException: Type 'InfoSheet' in Assembly 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers (System.RuntimeType type) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0 (System.Runtime.Serialization.MemberHolder _) (at :0)
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers (System.Type type, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo () (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize (System.Type objectType, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatterConverter converter, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder binder) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize (System.Type objectType, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatterConverter converter, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder binder) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteArray (System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.NameInfo memberNameInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write (System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.NameInfo memberNameInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.NameInfo typeNameInfo) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize (System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] inHeaders, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryWriter serWriter, System.Boolean fCheck) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] headers, System.Boolean fCheck) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] headers) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph) (at :0)
GigSheetManager.GetGigSheet () (at Assets/Scripts/GigSheetManager.cs:210)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:166)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:58)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:36)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:45)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

What am I missing. The string is serializing, but the list is not.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `Serializable` attribute to `InfoSheet` class definition.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  Without details we can only mark this as a duplicate of [Error - is not marked as serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15707872/3744182) or maybe [Type in assembly is not marked as serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31307365/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

Alexander, you are right. All I had to do is to add System.Serializable to the Infosheet Class. After I did that it worked! Thanks!